# Wordpress: Changing query_posts category according to page

Tags: wordpress, loops, post, categories

I have a custom page template in Wordpress which has a loop to display posts, this is currently filtered by a category using

```
<?php query_posts( array ( 'category_name' => 'holidays' ) ); ?>
```

followed by the loop. As there are many different pages using the same template but all needing a different category of post. I would like to make the 'holiday' part vary depending on what page you are on. Is this possible to add a condition and how? Otherwise I assume I would have to create many different templates for each page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way you could do this is with `is_page()`.

For example:

```
<?php if (is_page(pageIDgoesHere)) {
    $cat = 'holiday';
} elseif (is_page(pageIDgoesHere) {
    $cat = 'anotherCategoryHere';
}
?>
```

You could put this above your `query_posts()` and then use:

`query_posts(array('category_name' => $cat,));`

You could repeat the below `elseif` as many times as you need to:

```
elseif (is_page(pageIDgoesHere) {
    $cat = 'anotherCategoryHere';
}
```

Just use the integer ID of the page in place of `pageIDgoesHere` and set the desired category name where you see `anotherCategoryHere`.

This would alleviate having to add a query string to your page URLs.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `$_GET` attribute to your script.

```
$cat = $_GET['category'];

query_posts( array ( 'category_name' => $cat ) );
```

Then you access the page like this:

```
http://sitename.com/yourpage.php?category=holiday
```

Where "holiday" is the category.